# MAX Sale Amount by Customer per day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a Facts Table in which I have the Date , Customer ID, Sale Amount.

I need a column which help me to understand on that particular day what is max amount each customer spent?

For Example I am looking to get the MAX column from the below Dataset

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5iC5.png)

Comment: And what `GROUP BY` query have you tried?

Comment: Doesn't seem like they need a `GROUP BY` but a windowed aggregate (and probably a `CASE` expression).

Comment: I was trying to group by customer id but enable to get the expected results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the window function `max() over()`

**Example**

```
Select *
      ,Max = case when SalesAmount = max(SalesAmount) over (partition by Date,CustomerID)
                  then 'TRUE'
                  else 'FALSE'
             end
 From  YourTable
```

**On a side note:**  The window functions are well worth your time getting comfortable with.

Comment: Thanks John for your guidance

Comment: @user16352402 Always happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
select 
  t1.*,
  (CASE WHEN t1.SaleAmount = t2.maxAmt Then 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END) AS Max
From 
    table t1 JOIN
    (select
        max(SaleAmount) maxAmt,CustomeId,Date
    From 
        table
    group by Date,CustomeId
    )t2 on t1.CustomeId = t2.CustomeId and t1.Date = t2.Date
```